Angular/ASP.net core app throws "TLS connection" error after using Linux Docker Containers
I have just started a full-stack project with Angular (v18) at the front-end and ASP.net Core (.net 6.0) in the back, and I decided to use docker Linux containers (I have windows 11 Pro).
The problem is that I still have not touched anything yet, everything is like it is out of the box after i have created the project in Visual Studio except the container's HTTPS port number which I edited so my container can always be in the same port by specifying the "httpPort" and the "sslPort":
"Container (Dockerfile)": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true,
  "httpPort": 5000,
  "sslPort": 5001
}

Now I get this error when I execute both ends:
[vite] http proxy error: /weatherforecast
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1727:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I have tried a variety of solutions but none of which worked unfortunately.
NECISSARY NOTE: Everything was working fine initially when I was using windows containers (hyper-v) but when I wanted to use SQL server I had to switch to Linux containers (WSL) since SQL server's official image is available only in Linux containers, and that's when the mentioned problem started occurring.
This is actually my first time using docker so I apologize in case where I might be missing anything obvious.
My Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TaskManagerSol.Server/TaskManagerSol.Server.csproj", "TaskManagerSol.Server/"]

RUN dotnet restore "./TaskManagerSol.Server/TaskManagerSol.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TaskManagerSol.Server"
RUN dotnet build "./TaskManagerSol.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./TaskManagerSol.Server.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TaskManagerSol.Server.dll"]

I tried installing a TLS self-signed certificate in my machine, as well as modifying the compose.yml or the dockerFile it self but none of which did me any favor.

Please use default startup settings in your launchSettings.json.

Well first of all my default JSON file didn't look like this, it looked like the one I have referenced only without the last three lines which i have added my self. The reason they have been added is because if i remove them then my container will have a random pair of ports other than the ones i referenced in my Angular app causing another type of error.

Hi Othman, you can try to copy current project and remove all the docker related files and settings, then re-add the docker support for testing.
